# How to set google auth's reverse client id at build time for a react native app?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-oauth

My info.plist files contains the following, however it appears I'm not able to pass in GOOGLE_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID I defined in my `project.pbxproj` file. Is there a way to dynamically pass a string to info.plist during build?

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>${GOOGLE_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID}</string>
                <string>twitterkit-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
                <string>fb00000000000</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

edit:
It appears the naive version of including both works. Is there any reason not to do the following?

```
<array>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.123-staging</string>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.456-production</string>
</array>
```